# Calling some_object?.method() while some_object is null/undefined (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

What happens if you call some_object?.method() and some_object is null/undefined?

Comment: You can try it today in your chrome console. Anyway, the result of that expression will be `undefined` if `some_object` is either `undefined` or `null`

Comment: Thank you CRice for your answer. Believe me it is not that well known, and you may just put this as an answer, before I will and get my points :) haha what a sad place this platform has become...

Comment: I don't like figuring out. I like to ask questions.

Comment: Obviously no effort was done. Just go to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ enter `let some_object = null; some_object?.method();` and see the result for yourself.

Comment: I rarely use the browser console for testing JS... Maybe I should start!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional chaining syntax to optionally call the method by adding another `?.`

To safely call `method` here:

`_object?.method?.()`

Comment: Yes, but if you put the result of the function into a variable what will be the result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining